# WebHCAT Error in getting Hive Table Metadata. Command was terminated due to timeout(10000ms). See templeton.exec.timeout property","exitcode":143

Tags: hadoop, hcatalog

If I issue this webhcat REST call in my cloudera 5.4.1 environment

```
curl -s 'http://mywebhcat:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/default/table/person?
user.name=admin&format=extended'; echo; echo;
```

everything works fine and I see the metadata for the table Person.

But there is another table called foo_bar if I change the REST call above to

```
curl -s 'http://mywebhcat:50111/templeton/v1/ddl/database/default/table/foo_bar?
user.name=admin&format=extended'; echo; echo;
```

Then I get an error

```
{"statement":"use default; show table extended like 
foo_bar;","error":"unable to show table: 
foo_bar","exec":{"stdout":"","stderr":"which: no /opt/cloudera/parcels/
CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/hadoop/bin/hadoop in ((null))\ndirname: missing operand\nTry 
`dirname --help' for more information.\nlog4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.\njava.io
.FileNotFoundException: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/hive/logs/hcat.
log (No such file or directory)\n\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)\n\tat 
java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)\n\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.<
init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)\n\tat java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.
java:133)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:294)\n\tat org.
apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:165)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.
DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:223)\n\tat org.apache
.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:307)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.config
.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:172)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.config.
PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:104)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.
PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:842)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.
PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:768)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.
PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:648)\n\tat org.apache.
log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:514)\n\tat org.apache.log4j
.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:580)\n\tat org.apache.log4j.
PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.
common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jDefault(LogUtils.java:127)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.
LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:77)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.
initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:58)\n\tat org.apache.hive.hcatalog.cli.HCatCli.main(HCatCli.
java:65)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect
.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.
reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.
java:221)\n\tat org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)\nlog4j:ERROR Either 
File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [DRFA].\nOK\nTime taken: 1.035 
seconds\n Command  was terminated due to timeout(10000ms).  See templeton.exec.timeout 
property","exitcode":143}}
```

I don't know why it complains about a missing log directory only for foo_bar table but successfully returns the metadata regarding Person.

BTW, I can go into the hive console and do a select count(*) query on both Person and foo_bar.

EDIT::

Upon reading the error message again, it seems the core problem is

**Command  was terminated due to timeout(10000ms). See templeton.exec.timeout property","exitcode":143**

But cloudera manager is not aware of this property "templeton.exec.timeout" ... what do I do... I don't want to edit files manually as there are many many nodes in the cluster.

Edit2::

I went inside each hadoop node and did

sudo vi /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/etc/hive-webhcat/conf.dist/webhcat-default.xml

I found the timeout value and increased it to 1000000. I did this on each one and then I restarted Hive and WebHCat server using cloudera manager. but I got exactly the same error message.

Comment: Cynical take: any kind of "person" information gets automatically routed to some NSA database, bypassing Log4J config...

Comment: i tried to create the log file using `sudo -u hdfs touch  /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.1-1.cdh5.4.1.p0.6/lib/hive/logs/hcat.
log` but even that fails because this directory is sort of locked out.

Comment: were you able to resolve this?